# External disk - Unrecognized file system (-69846)

Tags: macos, terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, filesystem

I have an external storage with 2TB that was working nicely. But since last week, when I unplugged the USB before eject it, the disk is not readable anymore.

When I insert USB, I can actually see this message box:

[image]

**I also tried to repair it on Terminal:**

```
diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk2
diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk2
```

That results on this error:

```
Error starting file system repair for disk2: Unrecognized file system (-69846)
```

Can anybody help me please?

**EDIT**

Terminal comand `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk` returns:

> gpt show: unable to open device '/dev/disk3': Resource busy

(even after `umountDisk`)

---

Terminal comand `sudo fdisk /dev/disk` returns:

```
Disk: /dev/disk3    geometry: 1003/16/63 [1011242 sectors]
Sector size: 4096 bytes
Signature: 0x0
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Comment: What type of external storage, HDD or SSD and how was it formatted, HFS+? Have you tried plugging it in any other computer?  Sounds like you corrupted the filesystem beyond repair by pulling the USB without properly ejecting it first.

Comment: @user3439894 It's HDD. I guess that it was formated on Mac Os Journaling, but I am not sure! I already tested on another computer and same story - not readable. Is some way to repair file system?

Comment: It's going to depend on how damaged the filesystem on the drive is and the only suggestion I have is that if I was in this situation I'd try [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/index.html) if I really needed some files off of the drive.  As a last resort, If you can live with loosing what's on the drive, you can always format it and put it back into service.  Going forward, always maintain backups of files you do not want to loose.

Comment: IMHO, if the file-system is [munged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_(computer_term)) there's not much mere mortals can do. You could try [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) or [Stellar Volume Repair](http://www.stellarinfo.com/mac-software/volume-repair.php). As a last resort, you could contact [DriveSavers Data Recovery](http://www.stellarinfo.com/mac-software/volume-repair.php). I used DiskWarrior for a client a few years ago and it was partially, but not completely, successful fixing the problem. Disclosure: I have no financial stake in any of the companies mentioned.

Comment: @fiskolin Please unmount the disk and then enter `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk2` and `sudo fdisk /dev/disk2` and add the results to your question.

Comment: @klanomath the question is edited now with the results

Comment: @fiskolin have you tried diskutil repairDisc /dev/disk2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in the exact order:

```
#FOR THE WHOLE DISK
diskutil eject /dev/disk2               #Eject the disk 
diskutil mountDisk /dev/disk2           #Re-mount the disk

#FOR THE VOLUME(S) OF THE DISK
diskutil list                           #list volume identifiers. 
diskutil mount /dev/disk2sXXX           #Mount the Volume. Dont enter a disk ID
diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk2sXXX    #Repair the Volume. Dont enter a disk ID
```

Basically you are trying to correct previous mounting/ejection related errors by making sure the disk is safely ejected before you do anything else.

Once that is out of the way, have the disk re-mounted. Next, have the volume re-mounted. Finally, repair the newly mounted volume.

Additionally, double check for any human error. Did you want to repair the volume or the disk because you specified a disk identifier to repair a volume. You typed:

`diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk2`

it should be

`diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk2sXXX`

Or use `repairDisk` if you wanted to repair a disk.

Comment: I also noticed human error. You typed:

diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk2

Did you want to repair the volume or the disk because you specified a disk identifier to repair a volume. It should be:

diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk2sXXX

Or use repairDisk if you wanted to repair the disk.

Comment: thank you so much man to made my day it surely save ton of $$$

Answer (score 0):

Probably a long shot now, but you could try to open terminal and run:

```
sync
```

Sometimes fixes problems when a disk is physically removed before files are written to the disk (or if files deleted from the disk are still in trash).

Answer (score -1):

Just check the format. You probably have to format it correctly:
GUID Partition Table, Mac OS Extended (journaled).